# flutter build error caused by ffmpeg-android-java-2a627f6ecd.aar

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, android-ffmpeg

I have a `Flutter` app, previously builds/deploys all fine. Suddenly from last week (or maybe earlier) it gives this error

```
Launching lib\main.dart on TFY AN40 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
          
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
Could not resolve all files for configuration 
':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
Could not find ffmpeg-android-java-2a627f6ecd.aar 
(com.github.adrielcafe:ffmpeg-android-java:2a627f6ecd).
Searched in the following locations:
https://jitpack.io/com/github/adrielcafe/ffmpeg-android- 
java/2a627f6ecd/ffmpeg-android-java-2a627f6ecd.aar

* Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. 
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. 
Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 40s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

The problem is I didn't explicitly include ffmpeg-android-java in my project, it must be brought in by third party libraries I import, but I don't know which one. Has anyone experienced the same? Thanks in advance.

I tried to open https://jitpack.io/com/github/adrielcafe/ffmpeg-android-java/2a627f6ecd/ffmpeg-android-java-2a627f6ecd.aar to see what's going on, the page shows

```
Build failed. See the log at jitpack.io
```

My previous success build was two month ago, and it works fine, no code change, but this weeks build start failing due to this error.

Comment: Hopefuly you've already solved the issue. But in such cases you can check the dependency tree for example to know what library depends on this missing package (with `gradle androidDependencies` for example) and maybe change its version so it points to a fixed version instead of the latest one and thus it maybe would have a working sub-dependency.

Comment: Another option is to search the internet for the library docs, maybe it could say something useful to resolve the problem. And here you have a concrete lib name, just searching for it gives me a couple of pages with the exact same version, and someone seems had the same problem. And also there's a page for Maven repo link, for that version too. So maybe another solution would be to include `mavenCentral()` repository and see if it find the library.